# Connect Mysql server using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, server, vps

I want to handle multiple VPS using SSH connection in laravel 
I installed mysql successfully on 3 test VPS but now I want to create database in that servers so help me out

Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnD3J.jpg)

Comment: what version of laravel are you using 4.2 ? 5

Comment: 1st it seems MySql Server is offline. To create DB use command line or Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    SSH::run($command, function($line)
    {
        echo $line.PHP_EOL;
    });
}
catch(\RunTimeException $e)
{
    return view('dashboard.add_server');
}
```

I hope it will work for you